# Submit button working in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, post, button

I have a complicated view that holds another partial view. The partial view has a submit button.

The submit button and everything works fine in Chrome but in Firefox, even though Firebug shows no errors, absolutely nothing happens when I click the submit button.

Are there any typical issue to be aware of here? Maybe Chrome is more lenient with Javascript errors?

Anyone got any idea what could be happening?

The views are pretty huge so will not post everything

Edit: I will post the view with the submit button. I have put a form in a table to capture the values that I want to save:

```
 <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("RowPost", "Controller"))
    {


    <td class = "editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Minutes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Minutes)
    </td>
    <td>
         @Html.DropDownList("WorkType")
    </td>
    <td>
         @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.description)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description)
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />

    </td>
    }
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Maybe its something to do with the form inside a table row?

Comment: Could you at least post the code handling your `post`?

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Save Timeblock" />

Comment: sorry keep forgetting enter posts the comment! its just an input, and should call the post method in the view's controller, which it does fine in chrome. No errors in firebug, it just does nothing..

Comment: That input doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript.  I'm not sure anyone can help without any information to go on.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens".  Do you mean that the page doesn't even post back?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens. No post. No error in firebug console. Just nothing. I wondered whether it might be to do with the partial views I am using or javascript but firebug is not indicating any javascript problems. If I posted the 2 views and the controller code it would be so long that no one would read it!

Comment: ....ok, its working now and I have no idea why - I didn't change anything! Dunno if this has anything to do with it: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/797234#answer-154806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is not well formed and will result in invalid HTML, which in turn causes undocumented behaviour.

```
<tr> 
    @using (Html.BeginForm("RowPost", "Controller")) 
    {  
        <td class = "editor-field">
```

Results in something like:

```
<tr> 
    <form>
        <td class = "editor-field">
```

which is obviously not ok.  You shouldn't be putting forms inbetween rows and cells.  Try putting the entire table inside the form for more predictable results.

In future you could save yourself lots of headaches if you get to know and love the [WC3 Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).  If your html fails that, then get it fixed before worrying about anything else.